# ParserError: Expected identifier, got 'LParen' function (transfer)(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _

Tags: solidity, remix

Any help determining where I'm failing here would be helpful. I believe it has everything to do with my syntax, but am fairly new to DAPP development, but I believe the problem is in this line below. Thank in advance.

```
/// @notice Transfer the token from sender to the provided address.
/// @param _to Receiver of the tokens
/// @param _value Amount of token
/// @param _data Extra data for transfer
/// @return true/false
**function (transfer)(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool) {**
    require(transfer(_to, _value));
    require(_to.call(_data));
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
    return true;
}
```

---

full code below.

```
/// @title Token contract
contract Token is ERC20, ERC827, Mintable {
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) internal _allowance;

constructor(Token) public {address _autonomousConverter; address _minter; uint _initialSupply; uint _decmult ; {
        Mintable(_autonomousConverter, _minter, _initialSupply, _decmult); {
    }

/// @notice Provide allowance information
function (allowance, address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256) token ; {
    return _allowance[_owner][_spender];
}

/// @notice Transfer the token from sender to the provided address.
/// @param _to Receiver of the tokens
/// @param _value Amount of token
/// @return true/false
function (address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) token;
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_to != minter);
    require(_to != address(this));

    _balanceOf[msg.sender] = _balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    _balanceOf[_to] = _balanceOf[_to].add(_value);

    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/// @notice Transfer the token from sender to the provided address.
/// @param _to Receiver of the tokens
/// @param _value Amount of token
/// @param _data Extra data for transfer
/// @return true/false
function (transfer)(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool) {
    require(transfer(_to, _value));
    require(_to.call(_data));
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
    return true;
}

/// @notice Transfer the token based on allowance.
/// msg.sender must have allowance for spending the tokens from owner ie _from
/// @param _from Owner of the tokens
/// @param _to Receiver of the tokens
/// @param _value Amount of token
/// @return true/false
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) { 
    require(_to != address(0));       
    require(_to != minter);
    require(_to != address(this));
    require(_allowance[_from][msg.sender] >= _value);

    _balanceOf[_from] = _balanceOf[_from].sub(_value);
    _balanceOf[_to] = _balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
    _allowance[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);

    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/// @notice Transfer then token based on allowance.
/// msg.sender must have allowance for spending the tokens from owner ie _from
/// @param _from Owner of the tokens
/// @param _to Receiver of the tokens
/// @param _value Amount of token
/// @param _data Extra data for transfer operation
/// @return true/false
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool) {
    require(transferFrom(_from, _to, _value));
    require(_to.call(_data));
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value, _data);
    return true;
}

/// @notice Approve spender to spend the token ie approve allowance
/// @param _spender Spender of the token
/// @param _value Amount of token that can be spent by spender
/// @return true/false
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_spender != address(this));
    _allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

/// @notice Approve spender to spend the token ie approve allowance
/// @param _spender Spender of the token
/// @param _value Amount of token that can be spent by spender
/// @param _data Extra data for approval
/// @return true/false
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool) {
    require(approve(_spender, _value));
    require(_spender.call(_data));
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value, _data);
    return true;
}

/// @notice Transfer the token from sender to all the address provide in array.
/// @dev Left 160 bits are the recipient address and the right 96 bits are the token amount.
/// @param bits array of uint
/// @return true/false
function multiTransfer(uint[] bits) public returns (bool) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
        address a = address(bits[i] >> 96);
        uint amount = bits[i] & ((1 << 96) - 1);
        if (!transfer(a, amount)) revert();
    }

    return true;
}

/// @notice Increase allowance of spender
/// @param _spender Spender of the token
/// @param _value Amount of token that can be spent by spender
/// @return true/false
function approveMore(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    uint previous = _allowance[msg.sender][_spender];
    uint newAllowance = previous.add(_value);
    _allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = newAllowance;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, newAllowance);
    return true;
}

/// @notice Decrease allowance of spender
/// @param _spender Spender of the token
/// @param _value Amount of token that can be spent by spender
/// @return true/false
function approveLess(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    uint previous = _allowance[msg.sender][_spender];
    uint newAllowance = previous.sub(_value);
    _allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = newAllowance;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, newAllowance);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`function (transfer)(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool)`

You shouldn't use parenthesis for the function's name, delete them.

`function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) public returns (bool)`

---

Beside that, I see other errors in your code.

`function (allowance, address _owner, address _spender)` should be `function allowance(address _owner, address _spender)`

Also, why there is `token` at the end?

---

`function (address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) token;`

No name?

---

`constructor(Token) public {address _autonomousConverter; address _minter; uint _initialSupply; uint _decmult ; {...}` is wrong. It should be :

`constructor(parameters...) {...code}`

Comment: I removed the parenthesis frm arnd my functions name. I also removed token to reflect the line below, but I still receive ParserError: Expected token LParen got 'Identifier'
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256); . Clearly this is something I'm doing wrong. Again, thanks for all of your help   }

    /// @notice Provide allowance information
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256); 
        return _allowance[_owner][_spender];
    }

Comment: New error found.

Comment: Can you paste the updated code there are lots of syntax errors. @AndrewBotwin